# cannot find installed package in VS Code with TexLive

Tags: texlive, editors

My OS is win10 enterprise.

VS Code Output: ! LaTeX Error: File `algorithms.sty' not found.

I had set system environment path for me and all users, and found `algorithms.sty' in E:\texlive\2018\texmf-dist\tex\latex\algorithms

Also, I press update filename datebase in TexLive Manager-actions

I have tried many methods but it didn't worked, thank you for your time

[image: TexLive Manager]

[image: error]

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithms}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  asdlkjads
\end{document}
\begin{documeasdlkjadsnt}
\section{A section}
\begin{algorithm*}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm*}

\lipsum[1-15]% dummy text
\end{document}
```

i can compile that code as shown below

```
% !TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\author{Dongsheng Deng}
\title{Configuration of Visual Studio Code for \LaTeX{} Users}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, \cite{GraffZivin2018} sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation}

\bibliography{info}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling by command line?

Comment: @JouleV i just tried pdflatex test.tex, and it still output: ! LaTeX Error: File `algorithms.sty' not found.                                                                                                                                                                                                 Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,                                                                                  or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Comment: Then it is not a problem with your editor. You probably installed TeX Live in a wrong way.

Comment: On that tlmgr screen run the top 3 ACTIONS quit test and if necessary try the lower option update all installed then the top3 actions again

Comment: you have a second \end{document} followed by \begin{documeasdlkjadsnt} about 8 lines down they will not help so remove them

Comment: @KJO i just press 'update all installed' and run the top 3 ACTIONS, but i doesn't work :( , i can run other simple code, but if i use the package about 'algorithm', it will become error. Recently teacher asked me to write algorithm pseudo code with latex, that is the first time i use latex to write article, So i am very unskilled.

Comment: I think your problem is the name algorithms it is two packages but one is just {algorithm} so take the s off it should be \usepackage{algorithm} there are others algorithm2e, algorithmic but none are {al... **s}** and yes it is confusing since it say the "algorithms" package

Comment: @KJO Thank u very much! I just compiled successful by take the 's' off! VS Code Editor promote {algorithms} automatically when I write down '\usepackage{algo...}' and {algorithm} are not available in the options, but there are no package named algorithms, I think that this is the problem I have encountered.